# zurb foundation icon font with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, icon-fonts

i am trying to get the zurb foundation icon fonts to work within my rails project, though they dont appear to be working correctly

general_foundicons.css.sass

```
    /* font-face
@font-face
  font-family: "GeneralFoundicons"
  src: font-url("general_foundicons.eot")
  src: font-url("general_foundicons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), font-url("general_foundicons.woff") format("woff"), font-url("general_foundicons.ttf") format("truetype"), font-url("general_foundicons.svg#GeneralFoundicons") format("svg")
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

i have these files in `app/assets/fonts` though the fonts dont appear to be getting loaded

Comment: The comment `/* font-face` is not properly ended... can it be the cause of the error ?

Comment: its sass its properly ended

Comment: Did you check that your saas and font files are on the same directory? `src: font-url("general_foundicons.eot")`

Answer (score 9):

I use the [foundation-icons-sass-rails](https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails) gem. Extracting from their README:

Add foundation-icons-sass-rails gem to the assets group in your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> x.x.x"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> x.x.x"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'
end
```

Then rename your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` and add:

```
@import 'foundation-icons';
```

Now, you can use it as follows:

```
<i class="fi-[icon]"></i>
```

**Edit**

In Rails 4 you don't need an assets group. Additionally, make sure to install the latest version of the gem (3.0.0 as of 2014):

```
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> x.x.x"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> x.x.x"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails' ~> 3.0.0
```

Comment: You just saved me a massive headache

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your new fonts folder to the asset pipeline in config/application.rb? After that, I would try putting the block after `@font-face` in curly brackets and adding semicolons to the end of the other lines. If that doesn't do it, rewrite the `src` lines to `src: url(font-path("general_foundicons.eot"))` and so on, all as recommended at [this helpful link](http://aokolish.me/blog/2011/12/24/at-font-face-with-the-asset-pipeline/).